# Swagger API URL Parameter issue

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am new in swagger API Documentation, and want to deploy an API which is having query string. This is the API I am getting after passing the parameter in the GET method.

```
baseurl/v1/auth/getOTP?mobile=98XXXXXX14
```

and I want this:-

```
baseurl/v1/auth/getOTP/mobile/98XXXXXX14
```

what I am implementing is:-

```
"/auth/getOTP": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "pet"
    ],
    "summary": "",
    "description": "",
    "operationId": "findPetsByStatus",
    "produces": [
      "application/json",
      "application/xml"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "mobile",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "successful operation",
        "schema": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
          }
        }
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "Invalid value"
      }
    },
    "security": [
      {
        "petstore_auth": [
          "write:pets",
          "read:pets"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
{
    "name": "mobile",
    "in": "query", // <-- Right here.
    "description": "",
    "required": true,
    "type": "string",
}
```

In order to have the mobile number in path instead of query you need to change two things.

First, change the path to `"/auth/getOTP/mobile/{mobile}"`.

Second, change the parameter description:

```
{
    "name": "mobile",
    "in": "path", // This.
    "description": "",
    "required": true,
    "type": "string",
}
```

Learn more about OAS [path templates](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#path-templating-matching) & [parameters](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#parameterObject).